# Loud buzzing noise from newly installed motor in swamp cooler

Tags: noise, motor

I just Installed a new swamp cooler motor, 2 spd, on previous owners 1 spd wiring.

When i flip the switch there is a loud buzzing noise and the shaft doesn't spin. I Adjusted belt and no change.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "*I just installed a new swamp loud buzzing noise*" why did you install a swamp loud buzzing noise ?  Words !  I love the sounds of the swamp at night.

Comment: Lol forgot motor

Comment: More info is needed about motors and how you wired the "new" one.

Comment: Dial 115v 1/2hp, green to ground red to low and white to common black is not connected because the previous owner did not run a wire to black

Comment: How's the motor capacitor hooked up?

Comment: I'm not sure how it's connected

Comment: I feel a call for photos coming on!  OP it helps to attach an email/password to your StackExchange account, or alternately, a link to a Facebook/Google account.  By default, you post with a cookie-only account, and those won't let you [edit] if you change browsers (e.g. to a phone with a camera).

Comment: Borrowed the neighbour's motor worked perfectly so off to exchange the bad brand new motor